# Make the "body size" bigger

Tags: css, drupal

So I'm sorta new to CSS and Drupal, and I am trying to figure out a way to make the body be a minimum size. Here, you can take a look at the site I have at http://raptorshop.com

As you can see, the footer is huge and takes up half the screen. Would I just insert a box of sorts (maybe a wrapper?) and make it a minimum size, and put it in the middle?

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found the "min-height" thing.

Answer (score 1):

minimum is min-font-size

btw the link you provide seems like just to your host maybe ?